# Return an array with the length property of arguments passes

Tags: javascript, arrays, string-length

Currently Stuck on this challenges.

```
// stringLengths takes in four strings
// it returns an array containing the length of each string
// Example: stringLengths('mushroom', 'onion', '', 'garlic') returns [8, 5, 0, 6] 

function stringLengths(str1, str2, str3, str4) {

}
```

Curently have

```
function stringLengths(str1, str2, str3, str4) {
    var arr = [];
    for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        arr.push(arguments[i].length);
    }

    return arr;
}
```

This return me an empty array.

How can I push the length property of of each arguments into the `Array` and return the array with the lengths of each?

Comment: It works for me except for the fact that `i` must start from 0, because arrays are 0-based in JS.

Comment: yest tried tried it, started at index 0

Answer (score 6):

You can use of `...` and `Array.map` which are ES6 features. So you will handle any number of string.

```js
function stringLengths(...args) {
  return args.map(x => x.length);
}

console.log(stringLengths(
  'str1',
  'je suis un chocolat',
  'les croissants sont bons',
));
```

---

More concise

```js
const stringLengths = (...args) => args.map(x => x.length);

console.log(stringLengths(
  'str1',
  'je suis un chocolat',
  'les croissants sont bons',
));
```

Comment: I liked this because you esplicitly flatten the arguments instead of using the arguments object. FYI, this works with arrow functions, arguments doesn't. I'd suggest this as best answer

Answer (score 4):

If you just want an array of the lengths:

```
function stringLengths(str1, str2, str3, str4) {
  return Array.from(arguments).map((x) => x.length);
}
```

Should do the trick

Comment: According to MDN docs, `arguments` don't have `map` method so this is not valid implementation

Answer (score 3):

Your code is working fine, except you are starting at `1` instead of index `0`.
Arrays have a zero based index, hence I when you pass only 1 argument you get the initial empty array as the loop is not executed at all.

```js
function stringLengths(str1, str2, str3, str4) {
  var arr = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    arr.push(arguments[i].length);
  }

  return arr;
}

var x = stringLengths('123', '123456789', '12345');
console.log(x);
```

More Details on accessing array elements [**here**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Description)

Comment: Just to add, `arguments` is **not** an Array but is array-like and is zero based. It only has the `length` property of an Array. It does not have `shift` or `push` for example. You can however use Array methods such as `.map()` and even the spread operator on it (`...arguments`). See one of the other answers for an example on that.

Answer (score 2):

Your code works fine. You just need to start your loop with i=0 instead of 1, if you want all your arguments lengths.

```js
function stringLengths(str1, str2, str3, str4) {
  var arr = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    arr.push(arguments[i].length);
  }

  return arr;
}

console.log(stringLengths("hello", "okay", "doh"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the implicit object `arguments` you can get the keys, check for the attr `length` if a passed object doesn't have that attr.

```js
const stringLengths = function() {
  return Object.keys(arguments).map(k => arguments[k].length || 0);
}

console.log(stringLengths('ele', 'from', 'stackoverflow', 2222));
```